# How can I mock an Angular service using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have some e2e tests written in Protractor.
Some of my tests execute stuff that causes an alert to show (uib-alert).
The tests run fine and can find and verify the alerts, but if I use the tag dismiss-on-timeout from uib-alert, the tests fail because protractor waits for the timeout before doing the asserts.

Issues: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2798 and https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169

So, I want to create my alerts without the dismiss-on-timeout tag when running protractor.

My alerts are created by a Service like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory("AlertService", function (...
```

How can I override this on Protractor? I am trying to use browser.addMockModule('AlertService', mock) but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it by extracting the AlertService to a whole new module and then mocking it.
I guess protractor can't mock a single service inside a module, only the whole thing.

Edit:
I created alert.module.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp.alert', []);
angular.module('MyApp.alert').factory("AlertService", function($rootScope) {
...
```

And them, on protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
  ...
  function mockAlertService(){
    var alertMock = function() {
     angular.module('MyApp.alert', []);
     angular.module('MyApp.alert').factory("AlertService", function($rootScope) {
     ...
   }
   browser.addMockModule('MyApp.alert', alertMock);
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code sample for this?  I would love to see how you solved this issue.